# Is it possible to influence fontsize in a formula?

Tags: fontsize

Consider the following two snippets.

a.)

```
\[
\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)\left(\frac{q}{p}\right) = (-1)^{(p-1)/2 \cdot (q-1)/2}
\]
```

b.)

```
\[
\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)\left(\frac{q}{p}\right) = (-1)^{
    \frac{p-1}{2} \frac{q-1}{2}}
\]
```

The fraction in the exponent in b) is printed quite small relative to the other text. I have room to increase the size of the text. Is it possible to influence fontsize in a formula? If so, then how is it done in the example above b)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `\textstyle` in the superscript, but I'm not sure the result is nice. Better yet, use `\tfrac` and define a command for the Jacobi symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\jacobi}[2]{%
  \genfrac{(}{)}{}{}{#1}{#2}%
}

\begin{document}
\[
\jacobi{p}{q}\jacobi{q}{p}=(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}\frac{q-1}{2}}
\]

\[
\jacobi{p}{q}\jacobi{q}{p}=(-1)^{\tfrac{p-1}{2}\tfrac{q-1}{2}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now evaluate the results and take your pick.

Comment: I did not know about tfrac, it was what I was looking for. Thanks.